# How to return a named channel type that is read-only version of another channel type?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I have a code that is similar to this:

```golang
type Ch chan string

func getCh() Ch {
    ch := make(Ch)
    go func() {
        defer close(ch)
        ch <- "foo"
    }()
    return ch
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(<-getCh())
}
```

What I would like to do is to return a read-only version of the `Ch` channel from the `getCh` function. I've adding a read-only type that is compatible with the `Ch` channel, and changing the function signature to use this type like this:

```golang
type Ch chan string
type ChRo <-chan string

func getCh() ChRo {
    ch := make(Ch)
    // ...
    return ch
}
```

but this gives a compile error:

```
cannot use ch (variable of type Ch) as ChRo value in return statement
```

However if I drop the `ChRo` type and use native `<-chan string` as return type it works:

```golang
func getCh() <-chan string {
    ch := make(Ch)
    // ...
    return ch
}
```

Is there a way to use the `ChRo` type for the return value? The channel in my real code is not actually of `string` type - it is quite more complex generic struct.

As I understand it - the `ChRo` type matches exactly the type `<-chan string`. There is no [covariance confusion](https://go.dev/doc/faq#covariant_types) going on here.

#### Why

1. The first goal here is to have return a read-only channel type. It should be a separate type for readability. And it should be read-only so the consumer won't use it in a write context.
2. The second goal is to have the `getCh` function compatibile with another function that will be internally called by the `getCh`:

```golang
func getCh() <-chan string {
    data, err := fetchFromExternalResource() // returns (ChRo, error)
    // handle error
    return data
}
```

Comment: These are not type aliases, they new, completely independent types.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question. Is there any way to make it work using those types though?

Comment: No. `<-Ch` is different from `<-chan string` is different from `ChRo`. I don’t understand the goal here.

Comment: If it's different as you say, then how come the `func getCh() <-chan string { return make(Ch) }` compiles? Shouldn't it also be _different_?

Comment: Because `Ch` is assignable to `chan string`: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability

Comment: Yes, actually in this specific case `Ch` is assignable to `<-chan string`. But since `ChRo <-chan string` is not assignable to `Ch chan string` then I'm struggling to figure out how to return a read-only channel of a named type?

Comment: Is [this](https://go.dev/play/p/zUeP2b2WBgd) what you are looking for?

Comment: You would have to explicitly convert it because the named type is not assignable, like `return (chan string)(ch)` (though I’m still unsure why you would want this at all)

Comment: @Brits yest that's exactly it, thanks! I tried to convert it like this `(ChRo)(ch)` (it would be more readable) but it obviously failed. I haven't try to cast it to underlying type like you showed though. I guess it'll suffice. Thank you @Brits and @JimB.

Comment: Also @JimB I edited the question to explain why I want this.

Comment: People familiar with Go are familiar with `chan` and `<-chan`, IMHO trying to hide that does not help with readability.

Comment: @JimB that's a very interesting point. As I mention in the question: my actual type is more complex then simple `string`. It looked something like this: `type ChRo <-chan shared.Result[domain.Classification, domain.ProbabilityScore]`. That's why I wanted named channel type for readability. But you got me thinking if I should instead use named type only for this `shared.Result`, not for the entire channel. Thanks!

Comment: You may also want to use a type alias for that rather than a named type. If your underlying type has any methods they will not be part of a new types method set.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this: The type cannot (and imho) should not decide on how it is used. Interfaces define behavior, functions implement it.

So, the way to go would be to define one or more interfaces which define the desired behavior.

Having that said, what you want can be achieved.
Given the following code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type MyChannel <-chan string

type Stuff interface {
    // DoSomething implicitly requires a read-only channel.
    DoSomething(MyChannel)
}

type Reader struct {
    Prefix string
}

func (ms *Reader) DoSomething(ch MyChannel) {
    fmt.Printf("%s, %s!\n", ms.Prefix, <-ch)
}

type Writer struct {
    Prefix string
}

func (ms *Writer) DoSomething(ch MyChannel) {
    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s", ms.Prefix, "world")
}

func callStuff(stuff Stuff, ch MyChannel) {
    stuff.DoSomething(ch)
}

func main() {
    s := Reader{"Hello"}
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        ch <- "world"
    }()
    callStuff(&s, ch)

    w := Writer{"Goodbye"}
    callStuff(&w, ch)
    fmt.Printf("Received: %s\n", <-ch)
}
```

This [won't even compile](https://go.dev/play/p/vNDQoRaJ4X5), since the compiler correctly deduces that in `func (ms *Writer) DoSomething(ch MyChannel)`, we are trying to write to a receive-only channel:

```
./prog.go:25:2: invalid operation: cannot send to receive-only channel ch (variable of type MyChannel)
```

Without the `Writer`, it works as expected. <kbd>[**Run on playground**](https://go.dev/play/p/7vS4YdUrgLJ)</kbd>